# Error changing language for localisation Android

Tags: android, button, localization

Working on an Android project at the moment. I am trying to implement a button that will allow me to change the language from english to spanish. This is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //As soon as app is started up create an order object.
    order = new Order();
    order.setCovers(2);
    order.setTable(1);
    order.addToOrder(new MenuItem("Item 1", 12.99));
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "order size: " + order.getItems().size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    //reference to button and add listeners
    orderBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.orderBtn);
    orderBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Create a new intent and start up the sections activity...
            i = new Intent(v.getContext(), SectionsActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("data", order);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });



spanishBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.spanishBtn);
spanishBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Locale locale = new Locale("es");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale; 
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    }
});

}
```

The button does not change the language. It leaves it as english. However if I run my project with this code at the top of the activity it loads the text in Spanish.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("es");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale; 
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

What am I doing wrong? Any advice is much appreciate. What I hope to achieve from the above code is that app launches in english getting the string values from the values-en folder. Then when I click the button it loads the string values from the values-es folder.

CHANGE LISTENER TO THIS:

```
    spanishBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.spanishBtn);
spanishBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Locale locale = new Locale("es");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale; 
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        MainActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
});
```

still not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is to reload the activity after setting the default locale. So modify your code to this:

```
spanishBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.spanishBtn);
spanishBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Locale locale = new Locale("es");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale; 
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), YourActivityName.class);
   startActivity(i);
}
});
```

This will just reload the activity with the default language set to Spanish!